# Chromecast miniview in storyboard iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, chromecast

To display mini view with controls for chromecasting video in app , root view need to be changed progrmatically. the below code need to be added to the storyboard.

```
  // Wrap main view in the GCKUICastContainerViewController and display the mini controller.
  UIStoryboard *appStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *navigationController =
          [appStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNavigation"];
  GCKUICastContainerViewController *castContainerVC =
          [[GCKCastContext sharedInstance] createCastContainerControllerForViewController:navigationController];
  castContainerVC.miniMediaControlsItemEnabled = YES;
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
  self.window.rootViewController = castContainerVC;
```

But i made tabbar controller app , rootview intiated from storyboard. can somebody help me to change or modify the rootview to get miniView (container view) in tabbar application?

Answer (score 0):

Changing root view when using tab view does not look mandatory thing to me just try adding the complete navigationController object itself on the tab.
By this way on any one of the tab is will have your mini view with controls.